# NReco - wkhtmltopdf - Table of content(TOC) is not generating

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, wkhtmltopdf, nreco

I am using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 with NReco (Asp.net core).
I have set TOC to true

```
HtmlToPdf.GenerateToc = true;
HtmlToPdf.TocHeaderText = "INNEHÅLLSFÖRTECKNING";
```

I am getting document outline with the proper header text but toc is not generated.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 release: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3989

It fix that it is enough to upgrade to latest 0.12.6 release (or downgrade to 0.12.4 if this is not possible for some reason).

Comment: where I can download wkhtmltopdf binaries for azure Linux?

Comment: I don't know which binary i can use for azure linux..

Comment: If this is Azure Apps Service Linux VM most likely it is Debian-based; to check that you may connect to your Linux VM with SSH -- if you're able to use 'apt-get' it is definitely Debian-based.

Comment: Do we need to get library after installed in Linux? I have done extraction using 7zip. It doesn't work for me

Comment: When you use NReco.PdfGenerator.LT nuget package wrapper expects that you'll deploy/install wkhtmltopdf with your .NET app. In case of Linux deployment instructions depend on Linux distribution you use. If this is Debian-based Linux (but not Ubuntu) wkhtmltopdf should be installed with .deb package from the official downloads (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html). It is not enough to copy 'wkhtmltopdf' executable, it has many dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that part. I have installed debian-based linux and got the  binaries. When I export it in windows, it did not work.